# Why is my COM factory never released during the program lifetime?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, winapi, ole

I have a native C++ ATL in-proc COM server. A separate test program

- calls `CoInitialize()`,
- calls `CoCreateInstance()`, then
- calls `Release()` on the pointer,
- then calls `CoUnitialize()` and exits.

If I run the test program under Visual C++ debugger the debug CRT reports a single memory leak and each time the allocation number is the same.

I used [an allocation hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/820k4tb8%28VS.80%29.aspx) and found out that the object not being returned to the heap is the class factory object.

So basically the following happens:

- the program calls `CoCreateInstance()`
- COM internally calls `DllGetClassObject()`
- ATL instantiates the factory and passes ownership to the caller (COM internals)

and then the factory is never released - I don't see enough calls to `Release()` of the class factory.

What is happening? Is that a defect in COM runtime?

Comment: I'm not actually sure it makes a difference when calling `CoUnitialize()` but does you DLL export DllCanUnloadNow ?

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin: Yes, it does. `DllCanUnloadNow()` should only affect unloading the library, not releasing the factory.

Comment: I'm just musing out loud, but does explicitly calling either `CoFreeUnusedLibraries` or `CoFreeAllLibraries` make any difference?

Comment: @Phil Booth: Tried both - doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a problem of ATL implementation.

The server uses a global `CComModule` class instance. When `CComModule::DllClassObject()` is called it creates a class factory instance and caches it in the map referenced by the `CComModule` object. So in fact `CComModule` object owns the class factory. When `CComModule` destructor runs it doesn't release cached class factories.

In order to release all cached class factories `CComModule::Term()` method should be called before the server is unloaded. IMO the cleanest way to achieve this is to derive from `CComModule` and call `CComModule::Term()` in the derived class destructor.