# What is the purpose of malloc hooks?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

What exactly is the purpose of using malloc hooks? And I've read it's used in memory-profiling, etc. but never really understood how.

Comment: I not aware of the answer, but could you please post a link to where you have read this or post few sentences if its not available online. I would like to read it myself. Thanks.

Comment: I've read malloc hooks can be used to keep track of memory allocations, and profiling tools like Google Perf Tools(http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/), iguana MemProfLib (http://iguana.web.cern.ch/iguana/developer_guide/profiling.html) use the same to profile memory allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you can hook into the behaviour of allocation functions, then you can track memory allocations for profiling and debugging.

The GCC documentation on malloc hooks has [a nice little example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) demonstrating adding debug output every time the allocation functions are invoked.

I'm not really sure what else to tell you... is that not reason enough?

Comment: Adding debug output seems pretty simple, but profiling involves keeping track of all memory allocations and frees - and how do you manage to do that using hooks ?

Comment: @Raj: In exactly the same way? Output the information to some file or data store and analyse it after program execution.

Comment: Ok. So allocation hooks make just 10% of the profiling process, and the programmer(of the profiler) does the rest. I was thinking hooks take care of the majority of the profiling process and was expecting they would be much more complex. - Thanks.

Comment: @Raj: Yea. Big, clever profilers _may_ wrap it all into one place (I don't use any to know), but they certainly don't have to. In particular, recall that with the GNU profiler, for example, it's an additional step post-execution to run the data through the profiler itself (`gprof`). During your program's execution, hooks just record information and output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple example: suppose you know that memory allocated by allocation number N (N is the same in each run) is always leaked in your code. You can [set a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4154941) and inside put a breakpoint on condition "allocation number equals N". Once that breakpoint is hit you examine the call stack and find why exactly that memory is leaked later.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple way to make sure that your application is not leaking memory. This can be very important if it has to run for a long time in an environment with limited memory. You can use it while testing, and turn it off in the release version.

Answer (score 0):

They can also be used to replace the allocator altogether e.g. with umem or boehm-gc either for testing or because it is more efficient for a particular application.