# Investigating a bad free() pointer reference

Tags: c++, gdb, free

My program is crashing badly in an unitary test, due to a free() call to a bad pointer, with this error message:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/user/main.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x006d0065 ***
```

The code looks roughly like this:

```
// constructor is MyObj( const std::string & ) 
// and copies the string in its own std:string member
MyObject *obj = new MyObject("some string arg");
if(obj->isValid)
{
   log("Success\n");
}
delete obj; // if I remove this, the program doesn't crash...
```

My investigations have gone through this:

1. I tried to trace the pointers I create and free, but it occurs in a different address space, I get (successful) deletions like this: `Delete buffer @0x850ed0`. So I suspect something's trying to free a static char pointer. Also, the address stays the same over several attempts, which comforts me in this predicate.
2. I can't use GDB because the platform I'm using seems to bail out:

   `Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.`
   `[Switching to Thread 0x344314e8 (LWP 1443)]`
   `0x2a3dd658 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6`
   `(gdb) bt`
   `#0  0x2a3dd658 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6`
   `#1  0x2a3dea2c in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6`
   `Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC`
3. I tried to use hexdump to dump the address in the program on which the free() fails with this: `hexdump -C ~/main.out -s 0x6d0000 -n 2000`

   It gives me this (fault is `free(0x6d0065)`):

   `006d0060  e8 32 06 00 2c e6 02 5f  5a 4e 4b 53 73 34 66 69  |.2..,.._ZNKSs4fi|`
   `006d0070  6e 64 45 63 6a 00 ab 00  00 00 01 3e 58 00 00 1d  |ndEcj......>X...|`

   Which looks like a std::string function, which is quite strange...
   I figured this might be a bad use of hexdump, since the memory gets relocated when the program is loaded into memory.
4. I tried `readelf ~/main.out -a | grep 6d0065` to no avail as well (gives no hit)

I'm not a pro on debugging in these conditions; do you have any idea of how I could get what this address means to the program?

**Edit:**

- The program runs on an embedded platform (SH4); which is not supported by valgrind (very sadly...).
- Some more details on what this class does: it uses the [CUrl library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to retrieve an XML file on the internet, then proceeds to parse it with the [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) library.

Comment: Did you run your program through `valgrind` yet?

Comment: It is almost certainly due to a bug in the `MyObject`'s constructor, destructor, or both. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: `MyObject obj = new MyObject("some string arg");` won't even compile. Please post your _actual_ code. Code that looks "roughly" like what is causing the problem won't help us to help you solve it.

Comment: What are you doing in `MyObject`'s constructor and destructor?

Comment: `new MyObject` triggers a syntax error in C. Are you sure you want to write a multi-language source file?

Comment: Will malloc hooks (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5896887) help?

Comment: I removed the `c` tag. There is no way that this is C.

Comment: I don't like when people post code which doesn't even compile!

Comment: @Tomalak: valgrind won't run on the embedded architecture the program runs on.
@Tomalak 2: with a constructor like this: `MyObj(const std::string &string)` it will! It simply calls the std::string constructor *automagically*. 
I'll add more details in the question.

Comment: @Gui13 No it won't, because `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: @Gui13: Then build it on a platform that _does_ support valgrind, and run it there. Abstract away any hardware-specific details.

Comment: @Gui13: Wrong. `new` gives you a pointer. You would write `MyObject* obj = new MyObject("some string arg");`

Comment: @Gui13: So, when do we get to see your `MyObject` definition?

Comment: Tomalak: that is not the question. I'm looking for ways of investigating a bad free() call on an address which looks "static", by means of unix programs like *readelf*, *nm*, *hexdump* or ones I don't know. Showing the code of the actual object is: *1*) showing off more that 2KLOC, *2*) showing only a very small subset of a big set of interlaced classes in my project, which will confuse everyone off.Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly, in which case I'll reformulate: *how can I know if the address where free() fails is static in my program?* If yes, how can I know to what it corresponds?

Comment: According to report from provided GDB it looks like you trying to free same object in different threads more then once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally nailed the bug down.

For those interested, it was a structure that wasn't *zeroed* in the constructor of the class using it.

The schema was like this:

```
MyObj ---> BaseClass ---> structure member not initialized
```

Since this structure holds some pointers to strings, the NULL-check was failing and I'd free a bad pointer.

What's sad is that the base class usually would fill up every field of the structure, overriding the default garbage values. Only when I inherited the base class did I encounter the problem.

Looking back at this, I guess I could have found it *way* faster with a working GDB debugging.
I guess I'll have to look into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Wild shot in the dark... You have a base class that does not have a virtual destructor, and you are actually instantiating a derived class and storing the result of the new in a pointer to the base. You delete through a base pointer and the undefined behavior in this particular case is causing that effect.

Why do I believe that? The pointer passed to `free` has not being returned by `malloc`, as being an odd address it cannot be properly aligned, and `malloc` provides aligned blocks of memory always. That means that the memory that the pointer returned by the `new` and the pointer stored have an offset, which indicates that it is probably a base class. If the class had a virtual destructor, then the `delete` would be able to determine the most derived object type, and in doing so, it would correct the pointer to refer to the address that was allocated with the `new`. Without the virtual destructor, the `delete` is being transformed into `obj->~MyObject(); free( obj );` without correcting the offset.

Another thing that could cause the same type of problem would be allocating with `new[]`, and deallocating with `delete` (`new[]` will allocate extra space to store the number of elements, usually before the returned pointer). Again the problem would be that the pointer that is passed to `free` by the implementation of `delete` is not corrected to match the one returned by `malloc`... But in this particular case, the offset would probably not be an odd number.

Comment: Just a note: It's also perfectly legal to use an associative container to store the array lengths for `new[]`.

Comment: Right, @DeadMG, it was just one of the variants, at any rate this is shooting in the dark, there UB going on, and without seeing the code, and with the available data there is not much that can be done. I am inclined to the first option: non-virtual destructor in a base class.

Comment: This is some wild -- but not at all baseless -- guessing. Nice!

Comment: You know, this _actually_ makes sense.

Comment: MyObj effectively derives from a base class. I'll look into that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, after checking: my base class has a virtual destructor. OTOH, I don't store the inherited class pointer into a base class pointer, and I get a ~MyObj destructor called *before* the ~MyBaseClass desctructor is closed. I'll proceed check the created object pointer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Your class MyObject is doing something very, very bad.

And you can always (well, almost always) use the debugger. It's a bit challenging at times in some domains such as real-time programming, but this does not appear to be the case here.

To use the debugger in a meaningful way you code has to be compiled with debugging enabled, the -g option with the GNU compiler.

EDIT: My guess with regard to "doing something very, very bad" is that the class is deleting something that it has no business deleting. For example:

```
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject(const char * strarg) : str(strarg) {}
    ~MyObject() { delete str; }
private:
    const char * str;
};
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, and we already said all that in the comments.