# memory-allocation breakpoint does not stop execution

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, breakpoints

I have a piece of JNI code with a mem leak:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{76} normal block at 0x277522F8, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < "u' "u' "u'    > F8 22 75 27 F8 22 75 27 F8 22 75 27 CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

So, I set a breakpoint ont the specified memory allocation number (76 in this case).

```
_crtBreakAlloc = 76;
```

But the application never stop execution like if that allocation was never performed.

I also took two memory snapshots at the beginnning and at the end of the program, and I compared them.

(At code beginning):

```
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &s1 );
```

(At code end):

```
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &s2 );

_CrtMemState s3;
_CrtMemDifference( &s3, &s1, &s2);
_CrtMemDumpStatistics( &s3 );
```

Here the result:

```
0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Normal Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 2839 bytes.
Total allocations: 101483 bytes.
```

It seems that all is OK.

I can't figure out what is happening. Is it a false positive mem leak? Or is a memleak of the JVM? If so, is there a way to detect it?

**Added after the solution was found:**

I modified the initialization of a static `map` and the problem has been solved.
In particular, I transformed a private static member from `map` to `map*`. The problem is that when you initialize a static, it must be initialized with a constant.
Here is how I changed the declaration of the static member:

```
static const map<wstring, enumValue>* mapParamNames;
```

So my `initialize()` method becomes:

```
map<wstring, paramNames>* m = new map<wstring, paramNames>();
(*m)[L"detectCaptions"] = detectCaptions;
(*m)[L"insertEmptyParagraphsForBigInterlines"] = insertEmptyParagraphsForBigInterlines;
(*m)[L"fastMode"] = fastMode;
(*m)[L"predefinedTextLanguage"] = predefinedTextLanguage;
(*m)[L"detectFontSize"] = detectFontSize;
(*m)[L"saveCharacterRecognitionVariants"] = saveCharacterRecognitionVariants;
(*m)[L"detectBold"] = detectBold;
(*m)[L"saveWordRecognitionVariants"] = saveWordRecognitionVariants;

KernelParamsSetter::mapParamNames = m;
```

Finally, I inserted the `delete` of the map in the class destructor:

```
delete KernelParamsSetter::mapParamNames;
```

Hope this can be useful for someone.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking about, but I had success with an allocation hook http://stackoverflow.com/q/4154941/57428 in similar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be that memory allocation 76 occurs during the static initialization of a global variable. In that case, you may be setting _crtBreakAlloc too late to catch the allocation.

Comment: It would be nice if _crtBreakAlloc then reported something in the debugger; easy enough to catch. Is there a _crtGetBreatAlloc()? (I should google, I know)