# How to retrieve bytes being freed when using Allocator hooks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, profiling, hook

I am trying to implement a basic memory profiler within my application (yes, I know of the existence of powerful external software). I have been studying some online examples of how to use allocation hooks and I got the part of counting memory allocation to work. It is just about installing a custom malloc with `CtrSetAllocHook`, that looks more or less like the following:

```
int64_t memUsage (0);
int __cdecl MyAllocHook(
    int      nAllocType,
    void   * pvData,
    size_t   nSize,
    int      nBlockUse,
    long     lRequest,
    const unsigned char * szFileName,
    int      nLine
)
{
    if (nAllocType ==_HOOK_ALLOC)
    {
        memUsage += nSize;
    }
    else if (nAllocType == _HOOK_FREE)
    {
    //HOW-TO: memUsage -= nSize; ???
    }

    return(TRUE);
}
```

However, while when memory is allocated it is easy to increase a counter `int`variable that retrieves the size of stuff being allocated from `nSize`, I don't get how should I decrease such counter when memory is freed. The reason is that when `malloc` is called to free memory (i.e. nAllocType parameter= _HOOK_FREE_), the parameter `nSize` of the function above is always equal to zero. Which means we can't store the amount of bytes that were freed inside the malloc hook.

Could someone help me understand how could I use allocation hooks to also decrease the `memUsage` counter when `malloc` is called in free-memory mode?

Comment: Do you know that heap management stores info about size of heap blocks somewhere next to the actual data. You may find the size of the block to free when you decrement the `pvData` (by address size). Google for "MSVC heap management" (e.g. [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) may help.)

Comment: I'm afraid your tags are a little bit misleading. C++ has a "concept" of allocators which has nothing to do with your problem. ([**c++**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is questionable.) `_CrtSetAllocHook` seems to be related to MS CRT. (IMHO [**msvcrt**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msvcrt) is closest.) Actually, the C++ standard does not mention what new and delete have to use internally. In the case of Microsofts C++, it is probably something which is also used in their `malloc()` and `free()` implementations.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your comments. However, I'm afraid that are many obscure points in what you say. First, what does it mean to decrement `pvData` since arithmetic operations are illegal for void pointers? Second, after reading the doc you suggested, I don't how to use `pvData` to get back mem size. Intuitively I thought `(size_t*)(pvData)` or `(((size_t *) ptr) - 1)` could give it, but nope.

Comment: Needed some time to find this again but I did: [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html#table)

Comment: You should consider that heap frames may differ in debug and release binaries (but I'm _not_ sure about this...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In debug mode in Visual Studio 6.0 and 2008 (what version are you using?) the data pointed to by pvData is preceded by a [_CrtMemBlockHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270812(v=vs.60).aspx) struct which contains information about the memory.

Decrement pvData to get to the start of the header and get the slot nDataSize from the header struct.

```
int MyAllocHook(..) 
{
    else if (nAllocType == _HOOK_FREE) 
    {
        size_t headerSize = sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader);
        _CrtMemBlockHeader* pHead;
         size_t ptr = (size_t) pvData - headerSize;
         pHeader = (_CrtMemBlockHeader*) (ptr);
         size_t dataSize = pHeader->nDataSize;
}
```

Also, see the second answer here (for visual studio 2008):

[What useful things can I do with Visual C++ Debug CRT allocation hooks except finding reproduceable memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154941/what-useful-things-can-i-do-with-visual-c-debug-crt-allocation-hooks-except-fi?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, it not only did the trick, but also help finally understand how the mem blocks are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like @Angela Richardson's answer to my question better because it points to a more flexible solution that is provided, in Visual Studio, by using `_CrtMemBlockHeader`, I think it is also worth registering here that Visual Studio also allows the simple solution of using`_msize(void* ptr)`